# How to post a image/photo to wall of user or page?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I want to post an image or photo to wall of facebook user profile or  fan page.I am using graph api and C#.net.I am doing with web request.Here is my web request.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/pageid/photos?access_token=application_access_token&method=post&message=waterfall&source=D:\Image\image1.jpg
```

But getting an error. "message":

```
"(#324) Requires upload file"
```

I searched on the net for php fileupload=>true.I am doing in C#.I created a byte array and made a request in multiple part.But did not worked out.Does I need to write any thing in making  web request.Let me know.

Comment: source=D:\Image\image1.jpg – LOL …

Answer (score 5):

you can use the FacebookMediaObject:

```
dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.message = "picture caption...";
parameters.source = new FacebookMediaObject
{
    ContentType = "image/jpeg",
    FileName = Path.GetFileName(Picture_Path)
}.SetValue(File.ReadAllBytes(Picture_Path));
```

here's the full function to upload a picture to a user or to a facebook fan page:
**from my blog** http://www.codicode.com/art/graph_api_post_pictures_to_a_fac.aspx

Answer (score 4):

here is with javascript sdk and facebbok c# sdk:

```
function fb_publish() {
     FB.ui(
       {
         method: 'stream.publish',
         message: 'Message here.',
         attachment: {
           name: 'Name here',
           caption: 'Caption here.',
           description: (
             'description here'
           ),
           href: 'url here'
         },
         action_links: [
           { text: 'Code', href: 'action url here' }
         ],
         user_prompt_message: 'Personal message here'
       },
       function(response) {
         if (response && response.post_id) {
           alert('Post was published.');
         } else {
           alert('Post was not published.');
         }
       }
     );  
  }
```

and

```
var client = new FacebookClient("my_access_token");
dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.message = "Check out this funny article";
parameters.link = "http://www.example.com/article.html";
parameters.picture = "http://www.example.com/article-thumbnail.jpg";
parameters.name = "Article Title";
parameters.caption = "Caption for the link";
parameters.description = "Longer description of the link";
parameters.actions = new {
    name = "View on Zombo",
    link = "http://www.zombo.com",
};
parameters.privacy = new {
    value = "ALL_FRIENDS",
};
parameters.targeting = new {
    countries = "US",
    regions = "6,53",
    locales = "6",
};
dynamic result = client.Post("me/feed", parameters);
```

and would you please mark it as answered if it helps :)

Comment: i think that this answer is great

Comment: Thanks Eslam,for your help.I would like to know whether it will take my local pc image.That means image that stored on my hard-disk.

Comment: you can give it the url of the image not just the local pc image

Comment: I mean to say that image that stored on harddisk or requires a image that hosted somewhere(website).I am giving the url of the image.

Comment: i think that hosted will be better because some time if you put it in your local it will not appear

Comment: Hi Eslam Soliman,I was using graph api.I have taken facebook C# sdk from codeplex.I wrote ur code inside it.I don't have much experince in asp.net.That's why I am asking.I have one problem.The code contain var so have to define in script tag of aspx page or aspx.cs file and how to call function.Because facebookclient and ExpandoObject()is not visible in my code.(Not coming in green line)I am not getting ,how to proceed further?Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you be little more clear the code that i have sent is written in javascript sdk and another one with c# do not use C# if you are not a programmer

Comment: This is not relevant to uploading an photo.